# Update mapping table with new data and add alert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have data in a staging table that needs to be processed to my final transformed table.

My process is as follows:

1. Load data into staging table (using Azure Data Factory)
2. Stored Proc to process data to the transformed table

What is important in step 2 is that I have a mapping table which is used to compare with data in my staging table.

The mapping table has to be up-to-date. If a new country is identified in the staging table, and that country is not in the mapping table, the mapping table should be updated with the new country.

For example:

Table 1 = staging table

| Country |
| --- |
| USA |
| Brazil |
| Chile |

Table 2 = mapping table

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | Brazil |
| 3 | Canada |
| 4 | Peru |

In table 1, the country Chile is a new country in the staging table. Therefore, this country should be added to the mapping table.

Also, when the mapping table is updated with the new country, a notification should be sent to the relevant business unit that a new country has been added to the mapping table.

I am still new to SQL, and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using SSIS to move the data?

Comment: @SteveFord I am using Azure Data Factory.

Comment: I would start with a dataflow which finds the countries that don't exist in the mapping table and insert these into the mapping table first, then use a dataflow to insert the staging data into your destination table with lookups to get the right mapping id